# Restriction of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space and suppose that $\vartheta:C(X)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (with $C(X)$ I mean the continuous functions on $X$) such that $\vartheta(|f|)=|\vartheta(f)|$ (for each $f\in C(X)$) and $\vartheta(1_X)=1$. Furthermore assume that there exists $x_0\in X$ with $\vartheta(f)=f(x_0)$ for each $f\in C(X)$. Let $V$ be an open subset of $X$. Why is it true that $\vartheta(f_{|V})=f(x_0)$ for each $f\in C(X)$? Is this directly and trivial?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's true, or even meaningful.

First, $f|V$ has domain $V$, so at best it's an element of $C(V)$; $\vartheta$ isn't even defined on it.

Second, if we imagine that $f|V$ means "keep the values of $f$ on $V$, and set the result to zero elsewhere," so that at least it's defined on all of $X$, it'll generally not be continuous. So $\vartheta$ won't be defined on it.

Finally, look at a simple case: $X = (0, 2)$ and $V = (1, 2)$ (two open intervals in the reals). One possible definition of $\vartheta$ on $C(X)$ is that $\vartheta(f) = f(\frac{1}{2})$ (so $x_0 = 1/2$). How on earth can you descripe $\vartheta(f|V)$? There are surely two different functions in $C(X)$ that agree on $V$ but differ at $1/2$.

If you insist further that $x_0 \in V$, then I think that it almost makes sense, and is trivial once you get the definitions right.